# Can you respond to an expired message on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-messages

In January, I was sent an InMail, that I responded to, and got a response back. Now I would like to reply to the message with an update. The most recent message is marked as expired (after 90 days, as expected) (two others are 'responded' and 'replied'). The reply button is there, and when I write and send the message, I get the popup bar assuring me that the message was sent, yet I don't see it in the sent folder. Was it really sent?

Answer (score 1):

From the [LinkedIn Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/427/~/message-statuses-and-definitions) the definition of **Expired** message is as:

> - **Expired** - InMail status changes from "Pending" to "Expired" if the message isn't read within 90 days. The message remains active in the member's inbox and they may still reply. This status is most often used when referring to an InMail.

So the answer is Yes, you can respond an expired message.

This means your message has sent.

Other thing is if you don't find the sent message, click **Archive** or **Trash** and look there.